# O código da fila está com um erro no buscar. Como posso corrigir?

Tags: c, ponteiro, estrutura-de-dados

Eu utilizo a busca 2 vezes no meu código e trata-se de uma busca binária a fim de respeitar os critérios impostos no cabeçalho desse exercício.

Mas a dúvida consiste no módulo da busca binária pois o compilador me diz que os argumentos estão sendo passados de forma errada. Uso ColdeBlocks e a linguagem do código é C.

Vou colocar os 3 módulos envolvidos, inserir na lista, remover na lista e busca binaria.

Inserir na Fila:

```
int inserirNaLista(int ***l, int n, int x)
{
        int i, M;
        M=elementosNaLista(&l,n);
        if(M<n){
            if(buscaBinaria(&l, n,x)==-1){
                l[M]=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
                *l[M]=x;
                return 1;
            }

        else{
           return 0; //Elemento já existte
        }
     }else{
        return -1; //Overflow
     }
}
```

Remover na fila:

```
int removerNalista(int **l, int n, int x)
{
     int i, indice, M;
     M=elementosNalista(&l,n);
     if(M==0)
        return-1;// Underflow
        else{
            indice= buscaBinaria(&l, n, x);
            if(indice==-1)
                return 0;//Elemento não existe
                else{
                    if(indice== (n-1))
                    {
                        free(l[indice]);
                        l[indice]=NULL;
                    }else{
                            free(l[indice]);
                            for(i=indice; i<M; i= i+1) l[i]= l[i+1];
                            l[M-1]= NULL;
                    }
                    return 1;
                }
        }
}
```

Busca binária:

```
int buscaBinaria(int l, int n, int x)
{
    int inf,sup, meio,m,busca;
    inf=0;
    sup=(n-1);

    while(inf<=sup)
    {
        meio=((inf+sup)/2);

        if(l[meio] == x)
        {
            busca=meio;
            return busca;

        }else
        {
            if(l[meio]>x)
            {
                sup=meio-1;
            }else
            {
                inf=(meio+1);
            }
        }
    busca=-1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na função `buscaBinaria`, o teu primeiro parâmetro é um inteiro (`int l`) e tu tentas usá-lo como um array em `if(l[meio] == x)`.